# Why is a service invoked from outside angular not a singleton?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working on a project where I need to access a service from outside of the angular service.  Unfortunately, it appears that the service retrieved from outside of angular is not the same instance as inside the app.  In fact, it is a new instance every time I invoke it.  I created an example below to demonstrate the problem.

```
<div ng-controller="controller">
    <div>
        <span ng-bind="count"></span>
        <input type="button" value="Inside" ng-click="inc()"></input>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span id="outside-count">0</span>
        <input type="button" value="Outside" onclick="outside()"></input>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the javascript...

```
angular.module('Services', [])
.service('svc', function() {
    var svc = {
        count: 0,
        increment: function(){svc.count++;}
    };
    return svc;
});

angular.module('MyApp', ['Services'])
.controller('controller', ['$scope', 'svc', function($scope, svc) {
    $scope.count = svc.count;
    $scope.inc = function() {
        svc.increment();
        $scope.count = svc.count;
    };
}]);

var outside = function() {
    var svc = angular.injector(['ng', 'Services']).get('svc');
    svc.increment();
    angular.scope().$apply();
    document.getElementById('outside-count').innerHTML = svc.count;
};
```

What I expect is the outside count button will increment the same service object as I get in the `ng-controller`.  However, it gets a new instance every time, as consecutive clicks to the button always displays `1`.  The "Inside" button continues to increment the single service as expected.

Is there a different way I should access the service from outside angular for me to get the singleton instance of the service?

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/barnesjd/uB9Na/) of the above code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Services in Angular are singletons in the sense that they are only created once per injector.

`angular.injector` however creates a new injector function.

You need to get the current app injector: `angular.element(domElement).injector()`

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/BsLK8/

**Demo where inside stays synced**: http://jsfiddle.net/kW2BC/

Comment: So, is the only way to grab the correct injector via the app dom element? What if I don't know which element has the app, or if there are multiple apps? /cc @calebboyd

Comment: Perhaps pass an element id (of element with desired injector) into your onclick handler (outside) And use that for querying and attaining the desired injector.

Comment: Any DOM element within the app will do.

Answer (score 2):

You're creating a new injector from those modules, which is why you're getting a new instance of the requested service. Instead, you need to get the current injector belonging to the element that has the data/instance you need. To do that use this:

```
//assuming ng-app='MyApp' is on the html tag
//otherwise pass in the correct element.
var svc = angular.element(document).injector().get('svc');
```